# Are there any connections between the probability of poisson distribution when x=k and x=k+1?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, intuition, poisson-distribution

We know in poisson distribution, we have:
$$P(x=k)=\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$$
so
$$\frac{P(x=k+1)}{P(x=k)}=\frac{\lambda}{k+1}$$
I want to know are there any intuitive explanation of this result?

Comment: I guess you are asking: what does it mean to divide two probabilties?

Comment: @I.K.  No, I write this just because I think they have the same form, so I think there exit some collections between them. The relation need not to be div.

Comment: Do you mean connection rather than collection?

Comment: Yes, It's "connection", I made a mistake.

Comment: So you want to know if there is a connection between the probability of seeing `k` events and the probability of seeing `k+1` events? I'm just trying to pin down what it is you are asking.

Comment: @I.K. Yes, please explain if you know, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dividing two probabilities does not, in general, have any meaning.

Note that this ratio tends towards 0, all this tells you is that RATIO decreases.

The ratio shouldn't be surprising given the parameter $\lambda$